# How do I make resolv.conf work the old way on modern Linux distributions?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, dns, resolv.conf

In `/etc/resolv.conf` on modern distros link Mint 17 and Ubuntu 16, there's a warning:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

How do I make resolv.conf work the old way so that I ***can*** edit this file by hand, without  any other program or process overwriting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, you can specify base DNS servers for resolvconf at `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, which won't be overwritten. It uses the same syntax. That way you can keep running Ubuntu or Mint the default way. Then tell resolvconf to regenerate `resolv.conf` with `sudo resolvconf -u`.

However, you can remove resolvconf:
`sudo apt-get remove resolvconf`. It is safe to do so. Then write your desired DNS resolvers into `/etc/resolv.conf`.

You may not be able to use DNS management features in other programs that automatically manage your network (networkmanager) anymore.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with removing the `resolvconf` package, remove `/etc/resolv.conf` (on systems with the `resolvconf` package it will be a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`) and create the file with the contents you desire.

Comment: @Deathgrip: That's what I've done before, I but couldn't remember what it was that I did. Removing resolvconf is also a good solution.